# is there a way to define flags in java and run code only if those flags are defined?

Tags: java

In `c\c++` can define:

```
#ifndef <token>
    /* code */
#else
    /* code to include if the token is defined */
#endif
```

my question, is there a way to do it in java? (which is not defining a global static variable..)
for  example i want to run some code only in debug mode..

thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is No.  Not in the sense that you mean.

The way you do this kind of thing in Java as follows:

```
private static final boolean flag = true;  /* or false :-) */

if (flag) {
   /* code */
} else {
   /* different code */
}
```

Java doesn't have a preprocessor (like C and C++ do).  However, the compiler will optimize away the unused branch of an `if` statement like the above, PROVIDED that `flag` is a compile-time constant expression.  This is a limited form of conditional compilation.  Note that the controlling `flag` constant can be imported from a different class.

(IIRC, this behaviour is specified in the JLS ... which means that you can rely on any conforming Java compiler to do it.)

---

@Treebranch comments that "this" can cause code bloat.

1. If @Treebranch is talking about object code bloat, this is not true.  If you do this right with flags/expressions that are compile-time constant expressions as defined by the JLS, then the compiler does not emit any bytecodes for the "conditionally excluded" source code.  See @edalorso's answer.
2. If @Treebranch is are talking about source-code bloat, I agree.  But you can say the same thing for `#ifdef` conditional compilation.  (Macros and `#include` can be used to reduce source-code bloat ... but only at the cost of readability, maintainability, etc.  And that was the reason that the Java designers refused to support any source-code preprocessing.)
3. Java has a better way of dealing with platform differences, functionality variations and so on: use *dynamic binding*.  If having lots of different plugin classes in your JAR is a concern (bytecode bloat), deal with it by creating a different JAR file for each platform, or whatever.

Comment: The OP asked "is there a way to do it in java? *(which is not defining a global static variable..)*"

Comment: Java doesn't have global variables ... so technically that rider is moot.

Comment: One could argue that `static final` fields are the equivalent of global variables in e.g. C++ (from the usage point of view at least)... but your interpretation is confirmed by the OP's acceptance, so you get my +1 too :-)

Comment: @PéterTörök - static final fields are NOT global in the sense that variables can be global in C, C++ and FORTRAN.  They have to be qualified with a class name, and even then they are not necessarily visible.  Besides, my answer says *"No - not it the sense that you mean it"*.

Answer (score 5):

The approach that suggest that use of final static boolean variable is the closest to that suggested feature because it is even optimized by the compiler. If the flag is set to false the bytecodes contained in the block are not even generated.

Let me show an example:

```
public class Optimized {

    private static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if(DEBUG){
            System.out.println("DEBUG enabled");
        }
    }

}
```

This generates the bytecodes

```
public class Optimized {
  public Optimized();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
       3: ldc           #3                  // String DEBUG enabled
       5: invokevirtual #4                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
       8: return
}
```

But if we turn the flag off...

```
private static final boolean DEBUG = false;
```

The bytecodes look as follows

```
public class Optimized {
  public Optimized();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return
}
```

So, AFAIK, this is the closest you can get to a precompile directive in Java.

Answer (score 0):

The snipped you pasted above was a [conditional compilation macro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Conditional_compilation) meant for the preprocessor which "transforms" your source code before compilation.

Java does not have the equivalent language construct, so the anser is you can not do that.

**Edit:** You can do however use regular conditions to achieve your goal, since this way the compiler will optimize the bytecode in such way as desired (thanks for @StephenC for pointing this out).

But I personally prefer extending the API for debugging where needed which will hide the implementation details and can be changed runtime. Of course this is scenario-specific.

For example this would be similar to Log4j-s [API](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Category.html#isDebugEnabled%28%29), which lets you check if your code is in debug mode or not.

I would recommend the use of this pattern because that doesn't break (too much :) our beloved object oriented concepts.

Comment: *"You can do however use regular conditions to achieve your goal but that will not affect the build process depending on your token."* - Not strictly true.  If the condition is a compile-time constant expression, then the code is literally removed at compile time.

Comment: Yes, that is true but contrary to C/C++ where the preprocessor macros  tell explicitly which parts to cut, in Java the mechanics you described is implicit, thus not visible from the source code.

Comment: 1) It **is** visible in the source code.  All you need to do is **look** for the compile-time constant flags and where they are used.  OK, it doesn't stand out like a sore thumb ... like `#ifdef` does.  2) You should correct the mistatement I pointed out, and that (I think) you acknowledge

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing like conditional compilation in Java. (as xea said)

Depending on the problem you want to solve there a various ways to do something similar.

One is to use a static final variable set to a compile time constant (as Stephen writes). The compiler will actually not include the byte code for the impossible path. But it still has to be legal java, which means you can't declare a variable in one such block and use it in another.

I all the cases I have seen so far one could solve it using OO constructs. For example you can  replace your if else with a call to an abstract method and provide a debug and a production implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Java as a language has no similar preprocessing or macros like C or C++, however, there are [some](http://prebop.sourceforge.net/) [3rd party](http://www.slashdev.ca/javapp/) [preprocessor](http://code.google.com/p/java-comment-preprocessor/)-tools, which can handle things like these. For handy usage, you'd need to wire them up into a Maven- or Ant-build.

Answer (score 0):

I think what @StephenC has proposed is a good option. Alternatively, you can try using **AspectJ** to weave in code that you want for a particular implementation. You can then simply remove the aspect (don't weave in the code) when you don't want it as part of the implementation. AspectJ modifies the bytecode (compiled Java code) based on the types of locations (called pointcuts) that you specify. This is particularly well suited for things like adding logging to your program.

If this is an approach you are interested in, check out: [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) and [Reference Guide](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/semantics-pointcuts.html).

Comment: I would have to agree... nevertheless, it is an approach for the OP to consider. In the end it all compiles to bytecode.