# Class wrapper extending different base class

Tags: java, gwt

I have a Java project and now I also want to use this code for a GWT project so I don't have to write the same code twice. The problem is that some classes are not available in gwt, for example `java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D.Double`.

I was thinking of creating a wrapper class called `RectangleWrapper` that would extend either the standard Rectangle class or a `gwt` version of the same class.

In the shared code I would replace all my `Rectangle2D.Double` with my `Rectangle` and depending on a final boolean my wrapper class ([compiler flags java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9850445/is-there-a-way-to-define-flags-in-java-and-run-code-only-if-those-flags-are-defi) would either extend on or the other Rectangle class.

Is this even possible or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just took one of my GWT-project client-side classes and added the following lines:

```
    if (false) {
        String a = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml("lalala");
    }
```

This obviously compiles just fine, but when I launch the GWT app I get this:

```
  ERROR: Errors in 'file:/C:/gwtproject/src/main/java/package/ClientSideClass.java'
    ERROR: Line 119: No source code is available for type org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils; did you forget to inherit a required module?
```

So the answer would be no, you can't use a wrapper like that.

Is there any other way of achieving that? I highly doubt it.
One of the main features of GWT is replacing the old AWT/Swing desktop GUI components with a whole set of web GUI components designed for Javascript compatibility; there's no point in making the old components available or supported in any way.

If you were talking about utility libraries like Apache Commons, I could advise you to make an RPC call instead (client-side calls server-side where you can use anything you like, and return the results asynchronously), but that's not the case.